# regex: match between

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sample string:

> iasfa345.12isnhf Lat: 46.7132N, Long: 116.997W EFONA345.55SDF

I need to extract 116.997 and 46.7132 from it.

I only managed to get:

```
x.match(/Long: .{7}/g)
x.match(/Lat: .{6}/g)
```

But it includes Long: or Lat: that I need to substr() later.

The perfect solution would be to match any digit and a single dot between "Lat: " and "N or S" and between "Long: " and "W or E"

Comment: You may take coordinates into named group, and then use it instead of match result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `exec`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)</sup>* method:

```
var str = 'iasfaisnhf Lat: 46.7132N, Long: 116.997W EFONASDF',
    latPattern = /Lat: (\d*\.\d+)/,
    longPattern = /Long: (\d*\.\d+)/;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

alert(latPattern.exec(str)[1]);
alert(longPattern.exec(str)[1]);
```

If you need the direction indicators, which it seems like you would, the patterns would be:

- `/Lat: (\d*\.\d+)(N|S)/`
- `/Long: (\d*\.\d+)(E|W)/`

The direction indicators would be at index 2 of the object returned by `exec`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bFysk/).

Comment: the last 2 regex work great with direction indicators. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this format you can use this:

```
var str = "iasfaisnhf Lat: 46.7132N, Long: 116.997W EFONASDF";
var values = str.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, "").split(',');

values[0] == "46.7132"
values[1] == "116.997"
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WJcpD/1)

Comment: thanks, I edited my post to show that the string can contain other digits as well (and they shouldn't be included in the match)

Answer (score 1):

```
Lat:\s?(.*?)N
```

Extract the first group and it will contain the latitude.

```
Long:\s?(.*?)W
```

Extract the first group and it will contain the longitude.